# What causes the input to continue after letting go of movement keys?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Minecraft now, the longer I hold down a movement key the more delay there is for any keyboard action to the point where when I let go of <kbd>W</kbd> (move forward key) it'll take a second before I stop moving.

What is the cause of this and how do I correct it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, it's already a pretty accurate description, it happens to me, too: Hold W for 5 minutes, character moves forwards as expected, release it, character keeps moving forwards for a few seconds and then stops. I've seen this for a long time already, I just didn't bother yet to put in the time to check if it's due to Minecraft, my operating system, my wireless keyboard or anything else. @ToonLWind What's your setup? I'm using that wireless keyboard on a Manjaro+KDE laptop, no fancy accessibility features or such active (for keyboard at least), not sure if it happens in other programs.

Comment: I am using a ROCCAT Horde AImo keyboard and an EVGA Mouse on a bootcamped 2020 MacBook pro, so it runs windows 10. I'll also check if it does the same on other installations

Comment: OK, it could just be my modded, and only that, but still. I can't play like this.

Comment: I changed my character repeat settings. Problem SOLVED!

Comment: Well, what did you change them TO? Please post that as an answer.

Comment: I changed them in my roccat swarm settings (the keyboard driver)

Comment: Hey ToonlWind. Glad you figured it out, but please post it as an answer instead of a comment. You can answer your own question!